# Cannot populate ListView with SQLite database query

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-sqlite

I'm a complete newbie to Android development. My intention is to create an app which stores user inputs collected in EditText into an SQLite database and then displays them in next activity as a ListView. There are also some buttons involved, some of them are redundant as the app is still in its early stages.

When building the Gradle, there were no errors, also the `logcat` seemed to be completely OK with the whole thing. The first sign of trouble was checking the `/data/data/[projectname]` folder which didn't include any `.db` file or database directory. I have managed to make the transition between activities flawless, but since apparently there's no database in my project, nothing can populate the ListView.

I'm asking for some help determining what's wrong with my code.

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.peroalex.trackofworkinghours;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MyDatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    Button ADD, DISPLAY, DELETE, MODIFY;
    EditText DESCRIPTION, LOCATION, START, FINISH, COMMENT, ID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ADD = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        DISPLAY = (Button) findViewById(R.id.displayButton);
        DELETE = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        MODIFY = (Button) findViewById(R.id.modifyButton);
        DESCRIPTION = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.descriptionEdit);
        LOCATION = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.locationEdit);
        START = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.startEdit);
        FINISH = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.finishEdit);
        COMMENT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.commentEdit);
        ID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idEdit);

        databaseHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(this, null, null, 1);

        ADD.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                databaseAddData();
            }
        });
    }

    public void databaseAddData() {

        String addDSC = DESCRIPTION.getText().toString();
        String addLOC = LOCATION.getText().toString();
        String addSTR = START.getText().toString();
        String addFNS = FINISH.getText().toString();
        String addCOM = COMMENT.getText().toString();

        databaseHelper.addData(addDSC, addLOC, addSTR, addFNS, addCOM);
    }

    public void Action (View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, showRecords.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

MyDatabaseHelper:

```
package com.example.peroalex.trackofworkinghours;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by peroalex on 4/1/18.
 */

public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //Define database properties
    private static final int database_version = 1;
    private static final String database_name = "DatabaseRecords.db";
    private static final String table_name = "tasks";
    private static final String column_id = "_id";
    private static final String column_desc = "description";
    private static final String column_loc = "location";
    private static final String column_strt = "start";
    private static final String column_fnsh = "finish";
    private static final String column_comm = "comment";


    public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, database_name, factory, database_version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    //This code will be executed when creating a database, it includes the SQLite query which initiates a table
    String query = " CREATE TABLE " + table_name + " ( "
            + column_id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + column_desc + " TEXT "
            + column_loc + " TEXT "
            + column_strt + " TEXT "
            + column_fnsh + " TEXT "
            + column_comm + " TEXT " + ");";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);
    }



    //This method is used for deleting data according to given ID
    public void removeData(Integer ID) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + table_name + " WHERE " + column_id + " = " + ID + ";");
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table_name);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    //This method is used for adding data to the SQLite database
    public void addData(String dsc, String loc, String st, String fi, String comm) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(column_desc, dsc);
    values.put(column_loc, loc);
    values.put(column_strt, st);
    values.put(column_fnsh, fi);
    values.put(column_comm, comm);

    sqLiteDatabase.insert(table_name, null, values);
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
    }

    public Cursor getData() {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor data = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table_name, null);
    return data;
    }
}
```

showRecords:

```
package com.example.peroalex.trackofworkinghours;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * Created by peroalex on 4/2/18.
 */

public class showRecords extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    MyDatabaseHelper myDatabaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_records);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.displayDBListview);
    myDatabaseHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(this, null, null, 1);
    displayDB();
    }

    public void displayDB() {
    Cursor data = myDatabaseHelper.getData();
    ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
    while (data.moveToNext()) {
        listData.add(data.getString(1));
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

activity_main:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.peroalex.trackofworkinghours.MainActivity">

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/descriptionEdit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_description_black_24dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:hint="@string/description"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.052" />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/locationEdit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_location_on_black_24dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:hint="@string/location"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.14" />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/startEdit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_work_black_24dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:hint="@string/start"
    android:inputType="time"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.249" />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/finishEdit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_work_black_24dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:hint="@string/finish"
    android:inputType="time"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.337" />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/commentEdit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_comment_black_24dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:hint="@string/comments"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.448" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/addButton"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button"
    android:layout_width="90sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/add"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.297"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.628" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="80sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/delete"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.291"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.934" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/displayButton"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button"
    android:layout_width="90sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/display"
    android:onClick="Action"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.702"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.628" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/modifyButton"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="80sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/modify"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.708"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.934" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/insert_an_id_to_either_modify_or_delete_the_query"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.731" />

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/idEdit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_update_black_24dp"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:hint="@string/id"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.829" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_show_records:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/displayDBListview"
    android:layout_width="344dp"
    android:layout_height="551dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query to create the database is incorrect.You have forgotten to add `,` after `TEXT`, Hence your database was never created. Have a look at the code below

```
String query = " CREATE TABLE " + table_name + " ("
    + column_id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
    + column_desc + " TEXT,"
    + column_loc + " TEXT,"
    + column_strt + " TEXT,"
    + column_fnsh + " TEXT,"
    + column_comm + " TEXT" + ");";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(query);
}
```

Comment: I have corrected my mistake, but the ListView still remains empty.

Comment: It works!, Sorry for a wrong feedback, I just had to refresh the app. Works flawlessly, thank you!

Comment: @udit7395 actually  the database must have been created for the `onCreate` method to be invoked (the just created database is passed to the method). Hence why the resolution didn't work until the App was refreshed (data cleared and thus database deleted) as `onCreate` is only invoked when creating the database.